# HTML5 what is the itemscope attribute and what does it do in laymans terms?

Tags: html

I just wanted to know what is the HTML5 itemscope attribute used for basically?

Comment: This should be able to explain it to you in layman's terms: http://diveintohtml5.org/extensibility.html

Answer (score 72):

The `[itemscope]` attribute is a boolean attribute to define the scope of the metadata contained within the element.

It's defined in the [HTML5 Microdata](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#attr-itemscope) API:

> Every HTML element may have an `itemscope` attribute specified. The `itemscope` attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> An element with the `itemscope` attribute specified creates a new **item**, a group of name-value pairs.

In other words, it's a way of associating metadata with a particular DOM node.

This is used by the [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) API to associate data for search engines and social networks. [Google+ uses schema](http://schema.org/WebPage) as the way to provide titles, thumbnails, and descriptions for pages shared by users.

---

It should also be noted that `[itemscope]` and `[itemprop]` are compatible with Facebook's [Open Graph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) when providing meta data for a webpage. The same metadata can be listed for search engines, Facbook, and Google+ in a single set of `<meta>` elements rather than having to list the same information more than once:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>An Example Title</title>
    <meta content="An Example Title" itemprop="name" property="og:title" />
    <meta content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" itemprop="description" name="description" property="og:description" />
    <meta content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" itemprop="image" property="og:image" />
    <meta content="http://www.example.com/permalink" itemprop="url" property="og:url" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/permalink" />
  </head>
  <body>
    ...content...
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that in the example, `[itemscope]` was added to the `<html>` element. This means that any `[itemprop]` attributes in the `<head>` and `<body>` are part of the `WebPage` item.

Comment: It seems to have been split from the final HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/

Answer (score 35):

Search engines including Bing, Google, and Yahoo! are now using *itemscope* and friends to identify semantic data in webpages. On the website [schema.org](http://schema.org), they have an explanation of how to use *itemscope* with predefined schemas to improve the data that is provided to search engines.

http://schema.org/docs/gs.html