# Unable to grab img without a class using xpath in PHP

Tags: php

My code is:

```
<?php 

    $DomDocument = new DOMDocument();
    $DomDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $DomDocument->load($URLToFetch);

    $xpath            = new DomXpath($DomDocument);
    $divContainingImg = $xpath->query('//*[@class="n-car_preview__first"]');

    $imgHTMLCode      = $divContainingImg->item[0]->value;

?>
```

But when I try to output the code I am expecting everything from the div in which the img tag is, however, I am getting this errror:

`Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Specification mandate value for attribute itemscope`

I want to grab the first img tag inside of the div with that class `n-car_preview__first`but it's not happening. any idea what could be wrong?

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="n-car_preview__first">

    <img src="http://example.org/image-test.jpg" alt="Test image" width="320" height="240">

</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML

Comment: "The HTML looks like this" - maybe; but that's not the cruical part. The xml parser is complaining about an attribute `itemscope` that has no value assigned. The xml element in question looks like `<foo itemscope>` while the parser wants it to look like `<foo itemscope="something">`. I guess this is about [HTML5 Microdata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158876) and libxml not being too happy about the boolean attributes. Have you tried [DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) ?

Comment: No, now I am getting `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag nav invalid`

Comment: Then the libxml used by DOMDocument apparently isn't up to task of parsing html5. Since there is no (complete) DTD for html5 I don't know how to teach libxml that trick, sorry.